# Gradle creates huge number of files in project-directory

Tags: android, eclipse, file, gradle

-- using a Linux Mint system with AndroidStudio 2.3.3 -

Even the simplest "HelloWorld" project under AndroidStudio fills the projectdirectory with 1000+ of files ?? 
Is there  a way to avoid this or bring back the number of files to a reasonable quantity ?

( I remember when working with eclipse for Android the same simple project generated a 20+ number of files ? )
Thanks for any advice or explantion.
erics

Comment: These files are created by gradle, there is no option to override or avoid it, these files are needed by gradle build system.

Answer (score 0):

> Even the simplest "HelloWorld" project under AndroidStudio fills the projectdirectory with 1000+ of files ??

That isn't the simplest one. I just created one with 125 files in `app/build/`, which  my guess is the source of your complaints.

The project started with ~1100 files in `app/build/`. Most of the ~1000-file difference between the starting point and ending point were from dependencies, particularly `appcompat-v7`.

> Is there a way to avoid this or bring back the number of files to a reasonable quantity ?

Of all the metrics to be concerned about, the number of files in `app/build/` should be a very low-priority one. But, you are certainly welcome to remove dependencies from your builds to try to reduce the number of files.